# How to get the beta fitted value of linear model?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression, model-fitting

How to get the estimator hat beta for the beta parameter in the linear model?

I know there is this R function `fitted.values(object)` where in object one can write `f`, where `f<-lm(y~x)` where, for instance, `y<-c(1 2 ...), x<-c(3 4 ...)`

Where do I need to indicate that I want hat beta estimator?

Or if Is there another function on R such that gives the hat beta, please suggest?

Comment: Did you try `coef`?

Comment: @DouglasMesquita yes, thank you.